# Man leads a group out of a dark forest using his heart as a light

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know the name of this story about a man who courageously led a group of people out of a forest? The details are murky for me but this group was frightened to try to leave and he lead them out.

Throughout the story, they entered a really dark place and he ripped out his own heart which shined brightly and used it as a light to lead the way. At the very end, when everyone had made it out, he collapsed, and someone stepped on his heart to extinguish the light.

It's not a novel, it's a short story if memory serves correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is '**The Legend of Heliopher**' by Hardy Arnold, published in [Plough Magazine in 1938](https://www.plough.com/en/topics/culture/holidays/easter-readings/the-legend-of-heliopher) as an English-language retelling of the short folk tale *“The Flaming Heart of Danko.”* by Maxim Gorsky.

> And the people shouted, flinging their arms about in raging despair,
>   “There is no light, there is no sun!”
>
> But Heliopher called out, “Follow me!” And with his nails he tore open
>   his breast, and his heart burned with love, and it glowed and shed its
>   beams through the dark forest. Then he took it in both hands, held it
>   high over his head, and strode forth in front of the people.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Gah, you're wonderful. Thank you SO much, I've been trying to find it all day!

Comment: [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ). Don't forget to upvote and click the "accept" button